# In a View, is there an easy/automatic way to generate a table out of all data in a list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a list with 20+ columns and don't feel like manually building out the `<th>` and `<td>`.  Is there an easy/automated way to just tell MVC to generate a basic table with all of the data in a certain list?

Comment: A DevExtreme DataGrid will do this. Their tool stuff isn't free, though. https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/Overview/Mvc/Light/

Comment: use ef to reverse engineer the table to a class.  use mvc scaffolding to create a list view with the class. the link is for core, but the process is the same for mvc5 and below.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Comment: Unsure about automated way to create basic table but I would make such task simpler by using loops for both columns and data.

`// create list of headers and data
var headers = new List<string> { "Make", "Colour"...."Price" };
var cars = new List<CarObject> { Audi, Mercedes, RangeRover };`

`// use those lists in view by looping separately for header and data
<tr>
 @foreach (var header in headers) 
 {
  <th>@header</th>
 }
</tr>
@foreach (var car in cars) 
{
 <tr>
  <td>@car.Make</td>
  <td>@car.Colour</td>
  .....lots of columns here....
  <td>@car.Price</td>
 </tr>
}`

Comment: Can you give us an example on what the list can look like? Difficult saying a lot without seeing any kind of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using jQuery DataTables?

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

The view would then look something like this

```
@model  string[]

<script>
    var dataSet = [
        [@string.Join("], ", Model.Select(o => o))] // convert model to array data, you could also use a serializer here
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            data: dataSet,
            columns: [
                { title: "My strings" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```